# Execution of Java class file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I try to execute a java file within a package, the integrated terminal can't find the class file. How should I configure vscode or the command to automatically add the packages on the command like `java package.File` or search the class file automatically? I'm using `Code Runner` extension with this command: `"java": "cd $dir && javac -d \"$workspaceRoot/java/bin/\" $fileName && cd \"$workspaceRoot/java/bin/\" && java $fileNameWithoutExt`. This works when the java file isn't in a package.

Comment: One thing to try is to see if you can run the _same command_ in a non-integrated terminal (i.e. run `javac -d "PATH" filename.java && java filenameWithoutExt` locally. This might reveal the error, which I suspect is lack of a classpath argument to the `java` command line tool.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to use/create classpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `java` run as `<package>`.`ClassName`. For example, if your class looks like this:

```
package com.something;

class Something {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
};
```

And you run `javac` with the following:

```
javac -d . Something.java
```

Then, you need to make sure that `java` knows which package you want to run:

```
java com.something.Something;
```

In other words, you need to explicitly tell `java` what package your main class is in.

Basically, you need to create another variable inside of vscode that allows you to add the *package* to the beginning of the command:

```
"java": "cd $dir && javac -d \"$workspaceRoot/java/bin/\" $fileName && cd \"$workspaceRoot/java/bin/\" && java $filePackage.$fileNameWithoutExt
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner has a java package variable already defined, so it's something you'd have to either create by downloading the source of the package and hacking it, or requesting a variable from the package author at https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues

**Update**:

It looks like this is already an issue in the CodeRunner package: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/118. You might want to watch this issue for updates and upgrade your extension when it is fixed.

As a temporary workaround, I think just not specifying a package for your *main class* will work. All other classes are going to be using `import` anyway, so it doesn't matter for those, but keep your main class in the top-level package and VSCode Code Runner should work as expected.